Coefficient of the fractional Sobolev trace inequality
For a bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ with a Lipschitz continuous boundary $\partial \Omega$, and an integer $s \geq 1$. I have seen it stated that the following inequality holds,
$$ \| u \|_{H^{s-1/2}(\partial \Omega)} \leq C(\Omega, N, s) \| u \|_{H^{s}(\Omega)} \qquad \forall u \in H^s(\Omega).$$
However, I have not found an explicit formula for the coefficient $C(\Omega, N, s)$, I have seen proofs in the case when the domain is the upper half-plane, and proofs where the $L^2(\partial \Omega)$-norm is considered. However, I have found difficulty in proof of this statement for the fractional Sobolev norm.
I understand that the proof of this statement is in the paper Caratterizzazioni delle tracce sulla frontiera relative_ad alcune classi di funzioni in n variabili by Emilio Gagliardo. However, I have not found a translation for this paper, is there a source that I can read in English
